# How to find the version of OpenFOAM installed on WSL-Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openfoam

I have installed the OpenFOAM package via

```
sudo apt install openfoam
```

on Ubuntu, inside the Windows WSL environment. But I have no idea what version/variant of the FLOSS is installed. I tried the

```
blockMesh -help
```

hoping it would give me some information about what I am dealing with but I got the error message:

> --> FOAM FATAL ERROR :
>       Could not find mandatory etc entry (mode=ugo)
>        'controlDict'

Answer (score 2):

You can call the shell function `foamVersion` (which should be available when you install OpenFOAM):

```bash
foamVersion # in my case, the output is: OpenFOAM-v2112
```

Or simply see the output of the environment variable:

```bash
echo $WM_PROJECT_VERSION # in my case, the output is v2112
```

Comment: How should I install this script? I don't think that it comes preinstalled with the default Ubuntu package. Does it?

Comment: The `$WM_PROJECT_VERSION` environment variable is not defined. I get no output.

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani  If you've installed ESI version (e.g OpenFOAM v2112) you need to source it: `source /usr/lib/openfoam/openfoam2112/etc/bashrc` (assuming you're on bash).

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani: for OpenFOAM 10, you should do something like this: `source /opt/openfoam10/etc/bashrc`.  In both cases, you should add the source command to your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: The `/opt/` directory is empty. there is no `openfoam` folder in the `/usr/lib`. I did `find . -name "openfoam" 2>/dev/null` on my root directory and found `/usr/share/openfoam` with the `bashrc` script. Running it I get lots of `No such file or directory` error messages pointing to the `/usr/share/openfoam/bin/` path, which doesn't exist!

Comment: I posted a follow-up question [here](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/246949-there-no-bin-folder-inside-installation-directory.html#post842272)

Comment: @FoadS.Farimani: I think that's not the right way to install openfoam. To install ESI version follow the instructions [here](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/debian#ubuntu). For instruction how to install OpenFOAM Foundation version see  [here](https://openfoam.org/download/10-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ubuntu command

```
apt-cache show openfoam
```

I understood that I had installed the `1906.191111+dfsg1-2build1` version and the `openfoam.com` variant. But this is a Ubuntu-specific solution, not a general OpenFOAM solution that works on other operating systems.